# Django route returns AnonymousUser error even permission to route stays IsAuthenticated

Tags: django, permissions, anonymous-users

User extends AbstractBaseUser.
UserViewSet extends ModelViewSet.

my route

```
@list_route(methods=['patch'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
```

But after sending request to route, returns error 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'.

How anonymousUser can use this route, if permissions stays IsAuthenticated;

Comment: can you show your code ,what have u tried

Comment: ```@list_route(methods=['patch'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])<br/>
    def change_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.request.user
        serializer = UserWriteSerializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)```